# postgresql: Failing to connect locally via pgadmin3 (and phppgadmin)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin, phppgadmin

I am able to connect via command line but getting the usual error message in pgadmin3.

`Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

(and `login failed` in phppgadmin)

I know there are several q/a about this but none is addressing command-line success / pgadmin3 failure.

I have made the suggested changes such as:

adding `listen_addresses = '*'` in `postgresql.conf`

as also modifying trailing lines of `pg_hba.conf` as follows (to switch from peer to md5):

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
# host    replication    postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

what is more, connection in the following way fails:

`psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres`

(password failure)
however, connection like this succeeds:

`sudo -u postgres psql
Password: ****`

Comment: Change `md5` to `trust`

Comment: Password authentication failed means you passed in the wrong password. You could follow @wingedpanther's suggestion and change to `trust`, which allows you to log in without a password.

Comment: I have made several attempts and all of them succeed when attempting command line and failing in pgdamin3 (so the chance of wrong pass is extremely small).

Comment: changing to `trust` did not work either... when passing the same psswd I got the same error and using no passwd I got a `no passwd supplied` error

Comment: The lines in your `pg_hba.conf` only allow connections from localhost, try something like `0.0.0.0/0` for ipv4, and `::0/0` for ipv6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the server was listening to 5433 and both GUIs were trying to connect to 5432... the error message

`password authentication failed`

was very misleading though....